# Get values from ArrayList in DnnUsers

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have following `ArrayList` ..

```
RoleController objRoleController = new RoleController();

ArrayList UserList = objRoleController.GetUsersByRoleName(PortalSettings.PortalId, "Client");
```

I just want to fetch UserId and Display Name from UserList..What should i do???

Comment: Show me your full model, it's not giving any clear picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a view model that consists of just the UserID and DisplayName like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use one of two methods depending on what version of DNN you are using:

```
public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> GetUsersBefore73()
{
    var objRoleController = new RoleController();
    ArrayList UserList = objRoleController
        .GetUsersByRoleName(PortalSettings.PortalId, "Client");

    var users = from user in UserList.OfType<UserInfo>().ToList<UserInfo>()
        select new UserViewModel() {
            Id = user.UserID,
            DisplayName = user.DisplayName
        };

    return users;
}
```

In DNN 7.3 we deprecated the instance method and instead moved to using a factory to get the role controller.  We also stopped using an ArrayList and instead started using List.  For 7.3 and above you can use the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> GetUsersAfter73()
{
    IList<UserInfo> UserList = RoleController
        .Instance
        .GetUsersByRole(PortalSettings.PortalId, "Client");

    var users = from user in UserList
        select new UserViewModel() {
            Id = user.UserID,
            DisplayName = user.DisplayName
        };

    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UserList is a list of UserInfo objects.  You can get the values from properties of each UserInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
RoleController objRoleController = new RoleController();

ArrayList loUserList = objRoleController.GetUsersByRoleName(PortalSettings.PortalId, "Client");

DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo loInfo = new UserInfo();

foreach (var foUser in loUserList)
{
    loInfo = new UserInfo();
    loInfo = (DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo)foUser;
    int liUserId = loInfo.UserID;
    string lsDisplayName = loInfo.DisplayName;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.